# not getting any output on DOSBox when running my assembly code?

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

Im trying to run my code on DOXBox but i am not getting any kind of output. After use tasm then tlink the file and attempt to run it i get no output? Do i need to clear out a register? Could it be a memory issue? Im kind of stuck and i have spent the last hour trying to figure out what went wrong. Im far from an expert in assembly language code.

```
.model small ;small supports one data segment and one code segment
.stack 100h  ;used to push and pop registers/store return address when subroutine called
.386
.data ;creates near data segment for frequently used data
    welcome db '   Welcome to the store!!!$'
    menu1 db 10,13,'Please select an item: ','$'
    menu2 db 10,13, '1.Apples 100/- 2.Blueberrys 50/- 3.Carrots 20/-$'
    menu3 db 10,13, 'Select an option: $'
    menu4 db 10,13, 'Sorry need more than 3 option$'
    menu5 db 10,13, 'Add grocery option:$'
    menu6 db 10,13, 'Price:$'
    menu7 db 10,13, 'Press 1 to confirm new item or press 2 to return to menu:$'
    menu8 db 10,13, 'Enter quantity:$'
    menu9 db 10,13, 'Total price: $'
    menu10 db 10,13, '*****Order has been processed. Thank you*****$'
    menu11 db 10,13, '4.$'
    menu12 db 10,13, '/-$'
    menu13 db 10,13, 'To reorder: Press <1>$'
    menu14 db 10,13, 'Exit: press any key$'
    q dw 0
    r dw 0
    v db 0
    s dw 0
    rprice dw 100
    vprice dw 50
    sprice dw 20
    nprice dw 0
    var1 db 100 dup('$')

.code ;start of assembly code segment
    ;extrn indec: proc
    ;extrn outdec: proc
    include indec.asm
    include outdec.asm

    main proc
        mov ax,@data
        mov dx,ax
        mov ah,9
        lea dx,welcome
        int 21h

        start:
            cmp v,0
            jg start1
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu1
            int 21h

        menu:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu2
            int 21h

            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu3
            int 21h

            mov ah,1
            int 21h

            cmp al,31h
            je apples_
            cmp al,32h
            je blueberrys_
            cmp al,33h
            je carrots_
        
        menuadd:
            inc v
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu4
            
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu7
            int 21h

            mov ah,1
            int 21h
            cmp al,32h
            je menu

            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu5
            int 21h

            mov si,offset var1

        L1:
            mov ah,1
            int 21h
            cmp al,13
            je print
            mov [si],al
            inc si
            jmp L1
            
        print:
            call price

        start1:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu2
            int 21h

            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu11
            int 21h

            mov dx,offset var1
            mov ah,9
            int 21h

            xor ax,ax
            mov ax,nprice
            call outdec

            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu12
            int 21h

            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu3
            int 21h

            mov ah,1
            int 21h

            cmp al,31h
            je apples_
            cmp al,32h
            je blueberrys_
            cmp al,33h
            je carrots_

        additem:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu8
            int 21h

            xor ax,ax
            call indec
            mul nprice
            mov bx,ax
            jmp totalprice

        apples_:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu8
            int 21h

            xor ax,ax

            call indec
            mul vprice
            mov bx,ax
            jmp totalprice

        blueberrys_:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx, menu8
            int 21h

            xor ax,ax

            call indec
            mul rprice
            mov bx,ax
            jmp totalprice

        carrots_:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu8
            int 21h

            xor ax,ax

            call indec
            mul sprice
            mov bx,ax
            jmp totalprice

        price:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu6
            int 21h

            mov ax,0
            mov bx,0
            mov cx,0
            mov dx,0

            input:
                and ax,000fh
                push ax
                mov ax,10
                mul bx
                mov bx,ax
                pop ax
                add bx,ax

                mov ah,1
                int 21h

                cmp al,0Dh
                jne input
            add nprice,bx
            ret

        totalprice:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu9
            int 21h

            xor ax,ax

            mov ax,bx
            call outdec

            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu13
            int 21h

            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu14
            int 21h

            mov ah,1
            int 21h

            cmp al,31h
            je start
            
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,menu10
            int 21h

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
    main endp
end main
```

Comment: You have a typo: `mov dx,ax` (2nd instruction of `main`) should be `mov ds, ax`.

Comment: Found a duplicate for that error.  If there are other bugs, reduce your code to a [mcve] of just one problem, not a whole giant thing with a bunch of very similar blocks of code.  (Look up a different value from an array in one block, instead of duplicating the whole block and changing one variable name.)